# get all shortened urls on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get all shortened URLs for a page.

I already get all the urls on a page, may they be long or short.

if this isn't possible, how would I define a short url?

ie, which standards/rules must I check for?

using javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by short? `url.length < 25`?

Comment: @JasperdeVries, I mean those shortened URLs, ie bit.ly, tinyurl, etc.

Comment: @PeeHaa isnt there some kind of standard? length? pattern? etc?

Comment: @PeeHaa I was thinking about this, however doing some research, there are a lot of different providers, and could be custom.  Guess I will have to just use the more famous/most used ones.  I will gladly mark as answer if you post it.

Comment: So.. something like `url.length < 25` I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to automatically detect shortened URL's. This is because of the fact that they are just ordinary links like any other.

The best you can do is get a list of shortening services and match the links against that list.

As far as I can tell that will be the only option, because:

1. You cannot simply check the length, because that will give false positives
2. You cannot simply check for redirects, because that too will give false positives.

There is a pretty big list [here](http://longurl.org/services) of shortening services which may be useful to you.